# C# – Open XML SDK – Insert embedded Excel object to Word document

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to copy a table from Excel Sheet to Word Document as an Excel object. The table has a lot of formatting and colours and merged cells so I think the Excel object should be better than a regular Word table. I need the app to run on Mac, so I've chosen the OpenXML SDK.

I copied the table from the original Excel sheet to a new one with single sheet and single table and with help of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ee355229(v=office.12)) I created this code:

```cs
var lastId = document.MainDocumentPart!.Parts
    .Select(p => int.TryParse(p.RelationshipId[3..], out int result) ? result : 0)
    .Max() + 1;

_relationId = $"rId{lastId}";

var part = document.MainDocumentPart!.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>(
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    _relationId);

// Property Path contains path to the .xlsx file with single sheet and table
using (var fsEmbeddedDocument = File.OpenRead(Path))
{
    part.FeedData(fsEmbeddedDocument);
}

documentBody.AppendChild(new OpenXmlDocx.Paragraph(
    new OpenXmlDocx.Run(
        new OpenXmlDocx.EmbeddedObject(
            new OVML.OleObject()
            {
                Type = OVML.OleValues.Embed,
                DrawAspect = OVML.OleDrawAspectValues.Content,
                Id = _relationId,
                ProgId = "Excel.Sheet.12"
            }
        )
    )
));
```

But this creates `embeddings/package.bin` instead of `.xlsx` file. Also I know I need to create the ImagePart with `.emf` image of the table but I have no idea which data I should feed into it and how to connect it with the table.

Except for the article above I haven't found any related solutions or discussions. I've also read the related parts of the OpenXML Language Reference but I'm out of ideas so any help would be appreciated.